# How to remove Google fonts from wp-admin (Roboto) added by core

Tags: wp-admin, admin, wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-style, fonts

This line is in source of /wp-admin/ code. I do not wish to have extra Google fonts in Wordpress admin area.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='prefix-style-css'  href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:700' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

How to remove it? I have tried unsuccessfully this:

```
function my_dequeue_styles() {
    wp_deregister_style('prefix-style');
}

add_action('wp_print_styles', 'my_dequeue_styles', 999);
add_action('admin_init', 'my_dequeue_styles', 999);
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_dequeue_styles',999 );
```

Comment: please use plugin :https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-google-fonts/

Comment: @vikrantzilpe I see no reason to use plugin for 6 lines of code. BTW, this one doesn't work for me.

Comment: add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'tn_dequeue_google_fonts_style' );
function tn_dequeue_google_fonts_style() {
      wp_dequeue_style( 'prefix-style-css' );
}

Comment: Following code need to be added in the functions.php file.

Comment: one question for you which theme you are use?

Comment: @vikrantzilpe `prefix-style-css` is not a unique ID, `-css` is added later in process + it's wp-admin theme, no extra plugins.

Comment: try this prefix-style

Comment: @vikrantzilpe Please write a proper answer if you know the solution. Do not use comments for that. Thanks.

Comment: @hans no need to wride donw as answer, his approach is like mine and that doesn't work.